# Roles of parentheses in SQL Server SELECT queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

The following query returns no result and no error on SQL Server 2008 (tested on SP1), you can run it against any database, even master:

```
WITH computed_table (id) AS
(
    SELECT id FROM this_table_does_not_exist
)
(SELECT * FROM computed_table)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM another_table_that_does_not_exists)
```

On SQL Server 2005, you get an error because the tables do not exist.
You get also get an error if you remove some parentheses:

```
WITH computed_table (id) AS
(
    SELECT id FROM this_table_does_not_exist
)
SELECT * FROM computed_table
UNION
(SELECT * FROM another_table_that_does_not_exists)
```

The same kind of problems appears with real tables: on some occasions, the query does not return any result, and if you make some some slight changes, like removing a space or a carriage return, it works again...

I think that there may be a problem in the query, because the SELECT enclosed in parentheses may be interpreted as an expression instead of a subquery, as in [this page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:CEEDEIvJmWYJ:using-sqlite.labs.oreilly.com/re119.html+sql+parentheses+%22around+select%22&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=firefox-a). But that should at least return an error.

Am I missing something?

**Edit 26/06/2010**: I ran some profiling sessions, with the following results.

For the query above, the sequence of events is:

- Exception (Error: 208, invalid object name)
- SQL:BatchStarting
- SQL:StmtStarting
- SQL:BatchCompleted

For the query without parentheses:

- Exception (Error: 208)
- SQL:BatchStarting
- SQL:StmtStarting
- Exception (Error: 208)
- User Error Message (Invalid object name 'this_table_does_not _exist')
- SQL:BatchCompleted

For a working query:

- SQL:BatchStarting
- SQL:StmtStarting
- Showplan All
- SQL:StmtCompleted
- SQL:BatchCompleted

I also ran one of the queries with real tables that's causing me the same issue. The sequence of events is:

- SQL:BatchStarting
- SQL:StmtStarting
- SQL:BatchCompleted

No early "Exception" => the tables exist.
No "SQL:StmtCompleted" => it means that an error occured, I could not see any other reason why this event would not be raised.
No "Showplan All" => it means that the error occurs before (or when) the execution plan is computed. It may be caused by the combination of cte and parentheses.

I will raise the issue with Microsoft support next week.

Comment: have you tried changing the select *'s to actual column names?

Comment: what a wonderful question!  First, in 2008, you get errors on the second statement as well.  Also, I don't see that the UNION statement has anything to do with the strange behavior as removing the union and second select doesn't seem to change the results.  One interesting tidbit - when using the first statement, and asking for an estimated execution plan, I get no plan back at all.  I'm a gonna run a trace now.  TTYL.

Comment: Will you also post the code referred to by : "I also ran one of the queries with real tables that's causing me the same issue."  Also, out of pure curiosity, are you treating this as a blocker to development / a production issue?  If so, it seems that the workaround would be to not follow the cte, then parenthesis pattern.

Comment: I raised the issue with Microsoft on Monday. Today they classified it as a bug. There is no due date for the resolution, it might be fixed in a service pack or a later release.
They confirmed that there is no recommendation against the use of parentheses after a CTE, but it is a valid workaround.

Comment: AWESOME FIND!  Is it now in Microsoft Connect?  So, does my answer that it's a bug qualify as the accepted answer to this question?

Comment: @MaasSql - Seems to be fixed now. [Relevant connect item is here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/570888/parentheses-and-query-parsing-behavior-in-sql-server-2005-and-2008)

Answer (score 3):

So, I simplified the sql just a bit, as per my earlier comment on the original question.

```
WITH computed_tabled AS
(
    SELECT id FROM this_table_does_not_existd
)
(SELECT id FROM computed_tabled)
```

This seems to give us the same behavior.  Then I ran a trace.  Event classes :

- SQL:Batch Starting
- SQL:Batch Completed
- SQL:StmtStarting
- SQL:StmtCompleted
- Showplan All
- Showplan XML

What I caught was unexpected:

- SQL:BatchStarting
- SQL:StmtStarting
- SQL:BatchCompleted

Note: no SQL:StmtCompleted, no plans.  So, next, I go back to the capture settings, and add in every single Event Class under Errors and Warnings.  ReRun the query, and what do you know?  First caught event is:

```
Error: 208, Severity: 16, State: 1
```

Guess what [208](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917588.aspx) is?  But, the client never sees the error.

What I *think* is happening is that the code in the DBMS is saying - hey, they didn't ask us to return anything or do anything, so why bother?  Let's free up some resources for someone more demanding.

So I tried this piece of code:

```
--asdfasdf 
( SELECT 1 )
```

Which totally blew my theory away.  The parenthesis were NOT being interpreted as an expression.  Instead, they were being interpreted as a fully query ( which is to say, the client *is* asking for something to be returned ) and returned a recordset with 1 column and 1 row.  But no plan - probably b/c no plan was needed, as no db objects involved.

So, to mess with my mind some more I tried this:

```
declare @id as integer;
;
WITH computed_table AS
(
    SELECT id FROM this_table_does_not_exist
)
select @id = (SELECT id FROM computed_table)
```

Which, much like removing the parenthesis, produces a User Error Message.

I say, you're not missing anything.  I think this is an MS SQL Server bug.  It certainly seems related to the cte and the parenthesis.  I tried googling for mention of it, but didn't find anything.  This will give me something to talk about at the next local PASS meeting.  Sorry all I have to add to the situation is confusion. If I learn something, I'll be sure and post it here!

---

Update : 2010-06-26 10:09 CST
I went to Microsoft Connect in an attempt to find this listed as an issue. I was unable to find something around cte 208 or [cte invalid object](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=cte%20invalid%20object).  Honestly, I don't know of another bug listing site for sql server which one could check.  I also tried searching Microsoft Support and, again, Google.

Answer (score -1):

From the microsoft doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15, it looks like select with parentheses is only a special case in union parser. I doubt you can use it as a regular select.