# Where is the correct place to report a bug in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, bug-reporting

I have found a fairly insignificant bug in SQL Server 2008.

I would like to report this to Microsoft, however, when I went to https://support.microsoft.com/ I realized that I may need to spend $300 CAD to report it.

Is there a place where I can report this bug without it costing me any money?

---

Below is a sample of the bug:

**Works:**

```
USE [msdb]  
(SELECT * FROM msdbms)
```

**Fails with** *"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'."*

```
USE [msdb]  
(SELECT * FROM msdbms ORDER BY dbms)
```

---

*Also, if I am incorrect and this isn't a bug can it be explained why not?*

**EDIT**
I've added this to [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/588427/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-order-when-using-parentheses)

Comment: FYI unrelated to this specific issue but I tried to submit feedback regarding another bug on that site without any success using my various Microsoft accounts - kept going to "Please Wait...", error messages etc. I gave up and now regard that site as totally useless from a usability standpoint in that regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can report bugs at the sql server connect site https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer

however, here are 2 workarounds because you really don't need the parenthesis

```
USE [msdb]  
SELECT * FROM msdbms ORDER BY dbms

USE [msdb]  
select * from 
(SELECT * FROM msdbms) x
ORDER BY dbms
```

Comment: yeah, I've realized that which is why I think it's insignificant, but I'd like to report it because it doesn't work as I think it should.

Comment: @Nathan - Or bizarrely this also works `(SELECT * FROM msdbms) ORDER BY dbms`

Comment: ms connect was retired

Comment: Effective January 2018 the correct location is now: [https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server) for reporting bugs in SQL Server.

Answer (score 9):

Now that [Connect is being retired](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/collaborate/connect-redirect) thanks to GDPR, they've migrated all Connect content (supposedly!) to [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server) under the Azure feedback forums.  Bugs/issues/product-feedback should be directed [there](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server?category_id=325153).

Interestingly enough, they say "If you have a technical issue, please open a post on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) or [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=sqldocumentation%2Csqldatabaseengine)."  Not sure what they mean by "technical issue" and whether or not it's a synonym for "bug".  But, given that Connect was used for filing bugs while it was alive, it stands to reason that this new location, wherein they've migrated 4000 bug reports from Connect, would continue to be the correct place for such... but I'm no MVP or "insider" or whatnot, so hopefully someone closer to the source can verify this.

Comment: I had an SSMS bug that I almost decided not to report because the site was listed as an azure forum, not a SQL Server forum.  Good way to be sure you don't get necessary feedback on your products.

Comment: +1 This answer should become the new accepted one to avoid people missing the newer post and getting frustrated. Not all reports are equal. You can determine the correct forum for the request [SQL Server help and feedback - SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/sql-server-get-help)

Answer (score 1):

Connect is the usual site.

[Another parentheses related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119403/roles-of-parentheses-in-sql-server-select-queries).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like UserVoice (as others suggested) has been retired also! The new place to report bugs seems to be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The funnier or smellier bug/feature would be to get a wrongly sorted list by running the following:

```
USE [msdb]  
select * from (SELECT top 100 percent * FROM msdbms order by 1 desc) t
```

Because, apparently, by design, sorting with top 100 percent doesn't work. And the funny part is that you are allowed to specify order by even though you're not gaining anything by it.

It's more of a 'view' comment and it's not really a bug. But it's interesting to mention.

Comment: This is because `ORDER BY` has 2 different purposes in SQL Server. One is to order results for the client. The other is used in combination with the proprietary `TOP`  keyword. To say `TOP` according to what.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that, but while you're outputing the result of sorting and taking a part of it, why not output it in that particular order? Seems like defying the purpose and obscuring the concept. But, yeah, that's the way the cookie crumbles. :)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed bug in sql in my work place. I studied IT in management.
Problem is Pointer of mouse in rectangle
If pointer is held there <•••> after this sign
something is different.
I noticed this difference depending on this

1. using finger on touchschreen
2. using mouse to click on screen